# NoneType has no attribute 'n' in RSA OAEP encryption python

Tags: python, python-3.x, rsa, attributeerror, pycryptodome

In my attempt at making some sort of secure communications based "FTP" system, I encounter an error when my client-side program first attempts at encrypting data, it throws a single error that I see no examples anywhere else.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cli.py", line 63, in <module>
    sk.send(enc(fcmd.encode()))
  File "cli.py", line 31, in enc
    print(ci.encrypt(data))
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/Cryptodome/Cipher/PKCS1_OAEP.py", line 107, in encrypt
    modBits = Cryptodome.Util.number.size(self._key.n)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'n'
```

I do not understand the reason for this, as the key used is not an exported representation, but rather an actual RsaKey object. If you require more code snippets, please let me know as I cannot post the whole file here for size reasons.

Comment: It sure looks like `self._key` is `None`.  Did you ever set the key?  Are you sure it's `_key` and not `key`?  It's hard to know what's going on in the absence of any surrounding code.

Comment: @FrankYellin I cannot directly set those values, but I can indirectly set them in the cipher args. I used a simple version. Just `ci = PKCS1_OAEP.new(CPKEY)`

Comment: I can assure that CPKEY is a valid rsa key.

Comment: Can you look at the value of `self._key` before you call that last line?

Comment: I cannot, as pycryptodome is not under my personal development.

Comment: *If you require more code snippets* There's not a single line of code here except for the two that leaked into the exception traceback.